# Adding an Item to a TreeView which uses ItemsSource: Collection of Binding does not get the new Item

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview

I have a treeview specified in the XAML as follows:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView3Lvl" ItemsSource="{Binding objectsLevel1, Mode=TwoWay}">
... and some further elements in here ...
</TreeView>
```

On a button click I want to add an element to the treeview. Because I am using the ItemsSource I cannot add it directly to the list of items:

```
treeView3Lvl.Items.Add(newObject);
```

Instead it works by getting the ItemsSource and adding the element here:

```
 Collection<ObjectLevel1> itemsSource = (Collection<ObjectLevel1>)treeView3Lvl.ItemsSource;
            itemsSource.Add(newObject);
```

The element is visualized in the treeview, but the problem I have is that the collection "objectsLevel1" does not get the new element.
What do I have to do to make the collection included in the binding receive the new object?

PS: I also modify properties of existing elements. This works perfectly modifying the SelectedItem. Here the collection "objectsLevel1" gets the changed object.

```
ObjectLevel1 myobject = (ObjectLevel1)treeView3Lvl.SelectedItem;
            myobject.name = changeObjectName.Text;
```

Comment: Why don't you modify `objectsLevel1` collection directly?

Comment: Because I am following the MVVM pattern. Here I am in the View, the objectsLevel1 is in the ViewModel. And I want to figure out how this bi-directional binding works. ;-)

Comment: You're not implementing MVVM correctly. You're supposed to bind the view to the view-model and never touch any controls. Ideally, there should be absolutely no code in code-behind of the view.

Comment: Okay, I understand. How would I then get user inputs to the view-model? Only via binding of ICommands?

Comment: If you aren't using any MVVM libraries, then commands are the way to go. You can use delegate commands from one of MVVM libraries like *MVVM Light* or implement your own (they're trivial and there're sample implementations on SO). Some MVVM libraries implement more powerful and/or easy to use event handling, for example action conventions from *Caliburn.Micro*. But no matter how you handle events (through commands or by other means), you should never manipulate controls in your view-model.

Comment: While WPF expects developers to use MVVM approach, it doesn't include enough classes to make it easy. Consider using an MVVM library, it'll make things easier.